# Restart top-level actor in Akka 2.0.x

Tags: akka

From the documentation I understood that sending a `Kill` message to an actor will restart it, but what actually happens is it just stops.

(Is the documentation out of date?)

Comment: Which version of Akka are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new top-level actor which in turn creates the old top-level actor in its `preStart` method. This will be the supervisor, and the supervisor strategy can be set by putting this code in the new top-level actor:

```
override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
  case _: Exception => Restart
  case _: Throwable => Escalate
}
```

The `Kill` message still needs to be sent to what was the old top-level actor.

Comment: You should consider the use of scala.util.control.NonFatal

Answer (score 1):

Kill is "A message all Actors will understand, that when processed will make the Actor throw an ActorKilledException, which will trigger supervision.". So if the supervisor strategy of the parent actor of the killed actor is Stop, then it will not be restarted. In akka 2.1.0 you can configure the supervisor strategy of the guardian (i.e.: "/user/") which supervises the top level user-created actors.